# jquery ajax call returns object, how to get object value

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, json

So our programmer did an AJAX call that returns an object. I don't have a clue how to append the data it return to an element. Any help is appreciated.

AJAX CALL

```
$('.submit_btn').unbind('click').bind('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $(this).data('csrf')
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(ret) {
            var data = JSON.parse(ret.responseText);
            console.log('error');
            console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

After clicking the submit button, I get in the console "success" and:

```
Object {409: "Response message"} or Object {201: "Response message"}
```

And i should append the response message to an element. How can i access the response message?

Comment: console.log(data.409);

Comment: the data that was send from php is data since you didnt specify the data type type you should parse it

Comment: @DavidJawphan That's completely wrong, did you even test it? Use `data[409]`.

Comment: data[409] works, but sometimes it returns 409: "response message" and sometimes it returns 201: "response message"....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't always know the key returned (409 or 201), you can retrieve the response message of the data by doing:

```
data[Object.keys(data)[0]]
```

It will give you access to `data[409]` or `data[201]`

Comment: give us more explanation about this line @peter, It works perfectly but i dont know how

Comment: Object.keys() returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding to the enumerable properties found directly upon object. The ordering of the properties is the same as that given by looping over the properties of the object manually. Culled from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 3):

```
success: function(data){
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
  console.log(obj['yourfieldname_in_json']);
}
```

Comment: console.log(obj['409']);

Comment: you can also do this to access value console.log(obj[0][0]);

Comment: please add a brief description as to how this resolves the askers problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow, recommended reading [answer].

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
console.log(data["409"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
success: function(data) {
        if(data["409"]){        
        console.log(data["409"]);
        }
        else{
        console.log(data["201"]);        
        }
    }
```